# HTML table bottom property scrollbar

Tags: html, css, position, scrollbar, css-tables

When I use the following CSS code;

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 5;
right: 0;
```

It displays the table row with a vertical scroll bar, all I'm trying to do is basically stick something to the bottom right corner of a table row, then setting bottom to "5" to give it some room so no other divs overlap, in doing this, it displays a vertical scroll bar.

Is there anyway to remove the scroll bar, but ensure all of the content in the table row will show?

overflow: hidden; seems to not work.

Comment: Please add some HTML to demonstrate what you're doing. Are you applying that CSS to a cell, a row, or the table itself?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, wasn't applying it to the correct div.